# How to recover VMware Player Virtual Machine OS password? (Windows XP Professional SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware-player, password-recovery

Well, i think title is clear. :) I've tried all of my password combinations and none of them worked. If you can tell me a pratical way to do it, i'll be appreciated. :)

Comment: chntpw on a backtrack 5 live CD.  This will let you "zero" out the administrator password.  Just do a little googling on how to use it and how to boot a vm with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) is one of the easiest ways to actually *recover* the password. Simply download the ISO and boot the VM using the ISO. For the most part, Ophcrack will take care of the rest. Once booted, it will grab the hashes off the Windows partition and start cracking away. Provided it's relatively simple password, it should crack it handily.

If it's too complex, you could copy the hash and start cracking it using [Hashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/) or something similar.

You probably don't need to actually recover the original password however. If you don't have any files encrypted using your Windows credentials, you can simply reset the password using a variety of boot CDs. I like to use [TRK](http://trinityhome.org/) personally, it's handy CD to keep around.